# What's the cheapest non-shared webhost out there?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

IT has to be Linux hosting, let me set up whatever I want (node, mongo, etc)

Answer (score 2):

[Low End Box](http://www.lowendbox.com/) is basically a running tally of answers to this question.
Note: *low end*. All you asked for is cheap; you're going to get it.